# The implementation of serializing a sub-message in protobuf

Tags: implementation, protocol-buffers

I'm learning the implementation of protobuf. However, there is one point that i just cannot understand. How can the framework serialize a sub-message(object) into a buffer with a variable head, even sometimes it's length is really hard to figure out! Serialize it to somewhere else and copy it into buffer later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least four ways of doing that I can think of, off the top of my head - "which" is an implementation detail, as long as it gets the answer right:

- serialize to a separate buffer, then copy
- make an assumption about the length the header will take, skip that, serialize, then go back and fix-up the header (may involve a move, but not always)
- if you use a builder, it could be serializing individuallly as you add data, then composing later: in which case figuring out the length is trivial
- or it could have code to calculate the length of values without actually serializing

I've implemented it at least 3 of these ways, at different times!

Comment: Thanks for you answer. The four ways above might be some acceptable solutions. And personally, I prefer the second one(It seems more effective and faster than others).

Comment: @EdwardZheng that's what protobuf-net uses currently ;p

Comment: There is one extra way. You can serialize backwards to a buffer. When you write everything in reverse, the length comes after the submessage. Implementation is quite simple: you start at the end of the allocated output buffer and return a pointer to the start of the message when you are done.

Comment: @jpa as long as the buffer turns out to be big enough - otherwise you end of having to shove them on a stack, so you can't keep overwriting a single shared buffer

Comment: Yeah, so just for cases where there is an already allocated memory buffer for the resulting message. Another design choice about if there is a buffer and how it is allocated.